# Is it possible to export In design template for web re-use

Tags: adobe-indesign, export, automation

I have some templates of business card designed with "In design".
Those templates are generics with markups (name email ... )for merge data from Xls document with window -> utility -> data merge feature.

The question is : Can I export those template in JSON or XML output to use them in a website model list (like vista print or similar) ?

Once a customer filled those field required, I can easily call "In design" to map data into the template and print the business card... the hard part for me is to understand how to export my designs from in design into the website.

I draw a schema to show what the part of my workflow is missing (red bubble)

[image]

I saw in "In design" that we could export in XML but this is a pain in the ass to proceed to markup each single element. I want to know if exists some scripts or plugin / add-on for doing those things

Comment: Are you looking for a way to _automate_ the entire process, from the customer filling in the required fields to the final design being sent off to the printer? I don’t think that’s possible—too many individual factors in how printers want their files and things to take into account. I don’t follow quite what you mean otherwise. You can just export the merged InDesign document to a PDF file and then upload that to VistaPrint (or whatever service you’re using). I don’t understand how exporting an InDesign template to JSON/XML (you can’t, as far as I know) would help you…

Comment: I don't want to upload anything in vista print. I have a website, and on it I want to load all the "in design template" I have.

Comment: Hi Hooli, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat]. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: So what you’re really looking for is a way to take an InDesign document/template, replicate it graphically on a website (using HTML/CSS), and have customers enter their information into the appropriate places on the design; and then when they submit, you get the information they’ve entered as pure data, which you then load into the _actual_ InDesign template and print from there? That sounds like it ought to be feasible, but I don’t think there’s any simple, easy way of doing it.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes and no, I have the website and I can develop the part which recreate the template with html Css. I need a trick to export my templates from in design in a readable and useful way for another program.

Comment: Yes, the red box in your workflow there is exactly what I had in mind. Since you don’t need any InDesign-specific elements to be included in your exported file, it should be perfectly feasible to write a script to export your file to an XML file. It would entail the graphic designer adhering to some fairly stringent requirements to work, of course, in order for your parser to know which text frame is “Name”, which is “Position”, which is “Company”, which is “Phone number”, etc.; but it should be doable. I would guess you’d have to write your own script for it, though.